# Popup Menu Dialog Box in Linux

Tags: linux, menu, dialog

I use linux from day to day and have some rdesktop windows that I need to open quickly.  I wondered

**How do I make a popup menu dialog with a list of options** that I can choose from with maybe an **OK** and **Cancel** button too.

I am using `GNOME 3.10` by the way

Answer (score 3):

You mean from a shell command or script? In gnome environments you can use zenity to create pop up dialogs. For example:

```
zenity --list --text="Choose your favorite" --column="Name:" Opt1 Opt2 Opt3
```

This command will return the name of the option chosen (or empty if the dialog is cancelled).